# Automatic Delete post on a specific date

Tags: posts

i want to display all posts as well as count the days of the post since it was published

```
if ($pageposts):
  foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<p>';

   the_title();

   echo '</p>';
  endforeach;
endif;
```

Output should be something like this

Post Title1 - This post is published 4 days ago
Post Title2 - This post is published 3 days ago
Post Title3 - This post is published 6 days ago

and at the same time i want to delete the post once it reaches 10 days

I really need your help guys thanks i appreaciate it alot

Answer (score 1):

Use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-expires/

Answer (score 0):

There's a small thread in [WordPress support for this question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatically-delete-posts-after-x-number-of-days), they recommend two plugins, [Post Expirator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/) and [Auto Prune Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-prune-posts/).

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial 
- [WordPress: make posts expire or auto-delete](http://j3webworks.com/blog/wordpress-make-posts-expire-or-auto-delete)